# Is it "Advice companies to do something" or "Advise companies to do something"?

Tags: grammar

According to [this documentation](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/05/advise-advice/):

> Verb  Example     Noun    Example
>
> -ise      -ice

```
advise  || Jenny advised him to go home.    

advice  || My advice is to see your doctor.
```

So it should be:

Advise companies to do something?

Comment: *What* companies? I've never heard of them, but if they're a 'thing' it should be 'advice companies' (advice is a thing, advise is an action)

Comment: Oh when I read that documentation I really thought it should be advise in this context

Comment: "The consultant advised Company X to invest more in automation."  "The consultant said: 'My advice is to invest more in automation.'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, advise is the verb to give advice. Advice-noun, advise-verb. Not much more can be said on this- you advise someone by giving advice.